# having issues affecting the value of an initialized class through methods in python. it keeps overriding the value

Tags: python, class

```
class SmarJug:
    """"smart jug class  needs to be initially set contents to the value of 100"""
    def __init__(self, contents=100):
        self._contents = contents


    def pour(self):
        if self._contents == 0:
            print(f'Sorry this jug is empty!')
        else:
            print(f'Pouring...')
            self._contents = int(self._contents) - 25
            print(self._contents)
```

issue is that when i run test1.pour() logic happens but the initial value is set to 100 again

```
tes1 = SmarJug()
tes1.pour()
```

Comment: Can you include the code that actually causes initial value reset? Your code as posted is working fine (assuming indentation for method is proper). Are you creating a new `tes1` object anywhere?

Comment: how to you know that the value is set again to 100?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing you've shown resets the value. Sounds like you are expecting the variable to be stored across multiple executions of the code. This is not true. Every time you define `tes1 = SmarJug()`, the initial `contents=100`. Therefore each run "resets" the value...

If you want to persist the object state across runs, then you'll need to save/load the contents into a file, for example

```
import json
with open('jug.json') as f:
    contents = json.load(f).get("contents")
if contents is None:
    tes1 = SmarJug()
else:
    tes1 = SmarJug(int(contents))

tes1.pour()

jug = {"contents" : tes1._contents} 
with open('jug.json') as f:
    contents = json.dump(jug, f)
```